# SQL Server : SELECT from table updated during a Transaction

Tags: sql-server, transactional

I have a stored procedure that contains the following logic:

1. Starts transaction scope using `BEGIN TRANS A`
2. Calls a second stored procedure where a record in `Table1` is updated
3. Control returns to the original stored procedure where a `SELECT` is run against `Table1`
4. Commit transaction using `COMMIT TRANS A`

For some reason, that `SELECT` in step 3 is always returning the data values before the table was updated. I need the updated values from Step 2, that haven't been committed, to be returned by my `SELECT`.

How would I go about selecting the dirty/uncommitted data from `Table1`?

Comment: [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql)

Comment: In you scenario described you shouldn't need to read dirty data at all. Your transaction begins prior to calling the procedure. This means that procedure is run in the same transaction. After the procedure runs you can see the updated data in your original code.

Comment: Could you publish a repo script?

Answer (score 4):

The scenarios described sounds a little off to me. You can begin a transaction and then execute a procedure. The data affected by that procedure is part of the transaction. This is painless to test and demonstrate.

```
create table TransactionDemo
(
    SomeValue varchar(50)
)
insert TransactionDemo
select 'This is the original data.'

GO

create procedure TransactionDemoUpdate as
    set nocount on;
    update TransactionDemo
    set SomeValue = 'This is updated data.'

GO

begin transaction

select * from TransactionDemo --data prior to calling procedure

exec TransactionDemoUpdate --will update the data

select * from TransactionDemo --see the values have changed

rollback transaction

select * from TransactionDemo --after the rollback they are the original values again.
```